# Web Scraping with Python in combination with asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, web-scraping, python-asyncio

I've written a script in python to get some information from a webpage. The code itself is running flawlessly if it is taken out of the asyncio. However, as my script runs synchronously I wanted to make it go through asyncronous process so that it accomplishes the task within the shortest possible time providing optimum performance and obviously not in a blocking manner. As i didn't ever work with this asyncio library, I'm seriously confused how to make it a go. I've tried to fit my script within the asyncio process but it doesn't seem right. If somebody stretches a helping hand to complete this, I would really be grateful to him. Thanks is advance. Here is my erroneous code:

```
import requests ; from lxml import html
import asyncio

link = "http://quotes.toscrape.com/"

async def quotes_scraper(base_link):
        response = requests.get(base_link)
        tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
        for titles in tree.cssselect("span.tag-item a.tag"):
            processing_docs(base_link + titles.attrib['href'])

async def processing_docs(base_link):
        response = requests.get(base_link).text
        root = html.fromstring(response)
        for soups in root.cssselect("div.quote"):
            quote = soups.cssselect("span.text")[0].text
            author = soups.cssselect("small.author")[0].text
            print(quote, author)


        next_page = root.cssselect("li.next a")[0].attrib['href'] if root.cssselect("li.next a") else ""
        if next_page:
            page_link = link + next_page
            processing_docs(page_link)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(quotes_scraper(link))
loop.close()
```

Upon execution what I see in the console is:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'processing_docs' was never awaited
  processing_docs(base_link + titles.attrib['href'])
```

Comment: What is the point of asyncio usage in your program? `requests` performs HTTP queries synchronously anyway.
You need either run requests code by `loop.run_in_executor()` or replace `requests` with [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/)

Comment: @Andrew Svetlov, I got confused to see your comment. I really don't have good knowledge on this. Did I waste my time in vain then? I thought the program would run asynchronously - to be more specific: requests will be processed simultaneously other than queuing for one request to be completed.

Comment: No, `requests` is a synchronous library.
You could figure it out by absence `await` before `requests.get()` call.

Comment: BTW https://github.com/aosabook/500lines/tree/master/crawler is a async crawler example. It's written by Guido van Rossum and A. Jesse Jiryu Davis, uses aiohttp under the hood.

To be clear: I'm an aiohttp maintainer and wrote about of quarter of asyncio source code. I know what I'm saying very well.

Comment: Thanks  Andrew Svetlov, for your suggestion and the link. I'll go it through for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `processing_docs()` with `await`.

Replace:

```
processing_docs(base_link + titles.attrib['href'])
```

with:

```
await processing_docs(base_link + titles.attrib['href'])
```

And replace:

```
processing_docs(page_link)
```

with:

```
await processing_docs(page_link)
```

Otherwise it tries to run an asynchronous function synchronously and gets upset!